# MVC3: Set default values within "Code-Only"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, code-first, default-value

How to set default values for my "Code-Only" class (pass to sdf or mdf)? Does MVC3 release support this feature?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the default values via the class constructor. For example - I have the following data model class. I am using MVC3 and Entity Framework 4.1.

```
namespace MyProj.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Task
    {
        public Task()
        {
            this.HoursEstimated = 0;
            this.HoursUsed = 0;
            this.Status = "To Start";
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int AssignedUserID { get; set; }
        public int JobID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> HoursEstimated { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> HoursUsed { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateStart { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateDue { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }

        public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
        public virtual User AssignedUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I known about using constructor. And what about using MetadataAttribute? Is it posible?

Comment: @Calabonga - not that I am aware of. AFAIK the only way is through the constructor.